# Return ListBox with the lowest item count using LINQ

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I need to find a ListBox of six on a Form with the lowest number of items in it.

How can I use the `ListBox.Item.Count` property in conjunction with the extension method `Min()` from **LINQ** for returning the `ListBox` with the lowest item count?

I tried the following, but it's not working as I want it to:

```
foreach (var item in Controls.OfType<ListBox>())
{
    if (item.Items.Count <= min)
    {
        listbox = item;
        min = listbox.Items.Count;
    }
}
```

Comment: What isn't working as expected in your code? In addition if you are looking for a linq solution please provide a linq attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
ListBox b = Controls
    .OfType<ListBox>()
    .FirstOrDefault(lb => lb.Items.Count == listboxes.Min(l => l.Items.Count));
```